# Remove all file additional informations?

Tags: file

I had created an empty file  with file name (a),i noticed that the size of 65 bytes(with winrar), my question is how to create file without the additional informations like extension type, date of creation and other informations to make the file only 1 byte(the name of file) .

Comment: For that you need to write your own file system. Current file systems will have meta associated with file which will have that much size atleast! So in short no you cant create such file

Comment: thanks, do u mean file system like NTFS and FAT? and if this is the story ,is there any possibility to make one

Comment: Yep! But those are very heavy weight filesystems. You can google for basic file systems which just store mapping of file and its location on disk!

Comment: hhhhhhh u are fast in answer,thanx.

Comment: Should i post that as an answer so question will be marked as `answered`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to write your own file system. Current file systems will have meta associated with file which will have that much size atleast! So in short no you cant create such file. Here is something of interest if you really want to go down that path.

https://github.com/psankar/simplefs?files=1